# "error connecting to database" wordpress error when adding new db and site to multi-site vps

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx

For some context I am running multiple sites on a single VPS through Nginx, they are all WordPress sites.
The issue I am having is when I made a new site today and went to create a new Mysql DB for it and assigned a user using:

`GRANT ALL ON dbNew.* TO admin @'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newPassword';`

It broke the DB connections of all my other WP sites.

The only solution to restore the connections of all the other sites was to run the above command for a known working site that restored all other site's connections.

`GRANT ALL ON dbOld.* TO admin @'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'oldPassword';`

After extensive google searching, I've tried all recommended approaches including running in safe mode and turning MySQL on and off, flushing, etc.

I feel like I'm am missing something obvious here or there is some other error, I've followed the same process in the past without any issues, currently hosting 5 WordPress sites on this VPS and there are no hardware limitations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing two separate things with that command. Granting access to a new database for the user, and changing that user's password. You are not setting separate passwords for the same user for different databases.

Use of `IDENTIFIED BY` with `GRANT` is deprecated in MySQL 5.7 according to the Note in [this document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html):

> Use of GRANT to define account authentication characteristics is
> deprecated in MySQL 5.7. Instead, establish or change authentication
> characteristics using CREATE USER or ALTER USER. Expect this GRANT
> capability to be removed in a future MySQL release.

Comment: So I guess what I was trying to achieve was setting up a user/password for each new DB. Based on what you are saying I'm using the same user across all DB's, so when I was trying to make a new user I was actually changing the "admin" users password in the privileges?

Comment: Yes. That is how I understand it.